# How to normalize in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following question: A numpy array Y of shape (N, M) where Y[i] contains the same data as X[i], but normalized to have mean 0 and standard deviation 1.
I have mapped the array like this:

```
(X - np.mean(X)) / np.std(X)
```

but it doesn't give me the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want to normalize along a specific dimension, for instance -

```
(X - np.mean(X, axis=0)) / np.std(X, axis=0)
```

Otherwise you're calculating the statistics over the whole matrix, i.e. subtracting the global mean of all points/features and the same with the standard deviation.

Comment: I think i should make abstraction that it is a multidimensional vector and see it like a simple vector

Answer (score 0):

Use norm from linalg

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html

```
from numpy import linalg as LA

a = np.arange(9) - 4

LA.norm(a)
>>>7.745966692414834
```

Then you divide the array by the norm :

```
a/LA.norm(a)
```

Comment: It is still not ok.